# Enabling pptPlex add-in in PowerPoint 2013 64 bit (Windows 8)

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I know that pptPlex is designed for Office 2010 on Win 7 (the newest version of course).
But I have never seen anywhere that it *incompatible* with Office 2013. It is being installed successfully with Office 2013, but then the pptPlex tab does not show in PowerPoint.
I went to the Add-on settings and manually enabled the pptPlex addon, but it gives this message:

```
Not loaded. A runtime eror occured during the loading of the COM Add-in.
```

a strange thing is that it does not list the dlls from the pptPlex installation ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office Labs\pptPlex\"), but shows mscoree.dll in the add-on section.
Also, I didn't find any error message in the event viewer.

How can enable pptPlex for Office 2013? have anybody done that?

Update: as a user suggest, I must install pptPlex with Office 32-bit version. Is there anyway to make it work with Office 64-bit version?

Comment: Any chance you've installed a 64-bit version of Office 2013?  Might have to be 32-bit for PPTPlex to work.

Comment: yes, I'm. Anyway to install pptPlex on Office 64-bit?

Comment: You'd have to ask on the support page for PPTPlex, but as I understand it, it's sort of a proof of concept program that they may or may not continue developing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the result of excluding .Net Programming support while installing Microsoft Office.
after I enabled that option in Office setup, I could use the pptPlex plugin in the MS Office 64 bit.